# What does sed 's/$/END/g' do?

Tags: sed, command

I'm trying to work out what the command `sed 's/$/END/g' 2011.txt>2011.chr.txt` does.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` will read through the file: *2011.txt* and append: *END* to each line in that file, with all changes being output to the file: *2011.chr.txt*. For example:

| 2011.txt | 2011.chr.txt |
| --- | --- |
| line one text | line one textEND |
| line two text | line two textEND |
| line three text | line three textEND |

`sed` = stream editing utility

`s`   = substitute

`$`   = end of line

`END` = text to append

`g`   = globally

`>`   = redirect output from stdout to file

Comment: Note that the `g` flag at the end is not actually needed as the pattern is anchored and will only ever match in a single location on each line.